# How to return two elements from two multidimensional arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I struggle where I try to return (b[j]) to have both matching elements from arrays,any tips?

```
var newArray = []; newArray2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // we want to know if a[i] is found in b
    var match = false; // we haven't found it yet
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        if (a[i] == b[j]) {
            // we have found a[i] in b, so we can stop searching
            match = true;
            newArray2.push(b[j][1]);
            break;
        }
        // if we never find a[i] in b, the for loop will simply end,
        // and match will remain false
    }
    // add a[i] to newArray only if we didn't find a match.
    if (!match) {
        newArray.push(a[i]);
    } }
```

Comment: `newArray2.push(b[j][1]);` instead of this use `newArray2.push(b[j]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

Return as an object:

```
return {newArray: newArray, newArray2: newArray2};
```

or return as an array:

```
return [newArray, newArray2];
```

Answer (score 0):

return {found:newArray2, notFound:newArray}

please note you're maybe having a typo since you add b[j][1] to newArray2 but a[i] to newArray (as mentioned by Kenny in the comments)